# Any similar event to WM_PAINT in SDL(2)

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I created very simple program using SDL2 to display window generated from ray tracer image:

```
 auto* wnd = SDL_CreateWindow("Ray Tracer", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, s.width, s.height, 0);
while (!quit) {
   SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
   ...
```

While everything works, if I drag windows outside the screen and move back my windows becomes black. In windows APIs I had WM_PAINT, which would be sent to me in such cases. Is there similar event in SDL2?

Thanks for help!

Source code:
[Reference to source code](https://github.com/asyrovprog/ray_tracer)

Answer (score 1):

It is [SDL_WindowEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEvent) with `event->window.event` set to `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED`.